# Authorize attribute in MVC order, priority and function question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, roles

There is something in the roles I don't exactly get. using the `[Authorize]` attribute

**When you have the `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller and on the action:**

1. When a role is in both, this role will have access
2. When a role is only defined at the Controller, but not at the Action, no access
3. When a role is only defined at the Action, but not at the Controller, no access

I get that, that's logical. You need access to the controller before you can run an action.

What I dont get is why this doesnt work:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Algemeen Beheer, Admin, Coordinator, Secretariaat")]
public class FacturatieGegevensController : Controller {

    [Authorize(Users = "Stefan.coordinator", Roles = "Algemeen Beheer, Admin")]
    public ActionResult Create(int instID) {

        return View();
    }

}
```

When I am logged in as user `Stefan.coordinator` which has the role `coordinator`, I **can** access the controller, but I can not access the Create Action.
I thought this would be an OR relation between `Users` and `Roles`. Is it not? and how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The condition to access the Create method is:

> ((ROLE in { Algemeen Beheer, Admin,
>   Coordinator, Secretariaat })) *[from controller-level]* AND
>   ((USER in { Stefan.coordinator }) AND
>   (ROLE in { Algemeen Beheer, Admin })) *[from method-level]*

Once all the ANDs / ORs have been worked out, this results in simply:

> USER in { Stefan.coordinator } AND ROLE in { Algemeen Beheer, Admin }

That is, within a particular AuthorizeAttribute, the Users and Roles are ANDed together.  And across multiple AuthorizeAttributes, the conditions are ANDed together.

The best way to think of this is that the [Authorize] attributes are not aware of each other, so each executes independently.  The controller-level one goes first, then the method-level one goes.  To get access to the method, you need to pass all gates.

**Edit** - there was a question on how the logic works out as it does above.

Let:

```
A = ROLE is "Algemeen Beheer"
B = ROLE is "Admin"
C = ROLE is "Coordinator"
D = ROLE is "Secretariaat"
E = USER is "Stefan.coordinator"
```

Since the controller-level [Authorize] attribute is (A || B || C || D), the method-level [Authorize] attribute is (E && (A || B)), and multiple [Authorize] attributes are represented by a logical AND, the logic ends up as  (A || B || C || D) && (E && (A || B)), which reduces to E && (A || B), which requires the user to be named "Stefan.coordinator" *and* to be in the "Algemeen Beheer" or "Admin" roles.  Since the user Stefan.coordinator isn't in either of these two roles, the check fails.

**To your particular problem..**

If you want to apply your own logic to the [Authorize] attribute checks, subclass AuthorizeAttribute and override the AuthorizeCore method.  That way you can say if (User == "Stefan.coordinator" || base.AuthorizeCore(...)) { ... }.

Comment: Perhaps I am not following your logic, why is the `((USER in { Stefan.coordinator })` being eliminated?

Comment: @Nathan - I've posted a clarification.  Please let me know if this answers your question!

Comment: there is a mistake in your equation. It seems to be ((USER in { Stefan.coordinator }) **AND** (ROLE in { Algemeen Beheer, Admin })) [from method-level] because no other user can access the Action when it has this user-tag

Comment: Bah, can't believe I forgot how that code worked. -_-  Updating answer.